# Chunking Stanford Parser

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am wondering how to use `Regex` to chunk a Tree structure generated from NLTK's

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
```

A sentence: **"New Jersey Imports of Residual Fuel Oil, Greater Than 1% Sulfur"**. A tree generated from Stanford Parser looks like this:

```
(ROOT
  (NP
    (NP (NNP New) (NNP Jersey))
    (NP
      (NP (NNS Imports))
      (PP
        (IN of)
        (NP
          (NP (NNP Residual) (NN Fuel) (NN Oil))
          (, ,)
          (NP
            (NP (NNP Greater))
            (PP (IN Than) (NP (ADJP (CD 1) (NN %)) (NN Sulfur)))))))))
```

I want to extract the following phrase, tokenized in tuples:

```
[('New', 'Jersey'), ('Imports'), ('Residual', 'Fuel', 'Oil'), ('Greater', 'Than', '1', '%', 'Sulfur')]
```

When I try to get all the subtrees(excluding the tree itself), I get something like this:

```
(u'New', u'Jersey')
(u'Imports', u'of', u'Residual', u'Fuel', u'Oil', u',', u'Greater', u'Than', u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'Imports',)
(u'of', u'Residual', u'Fuel', u'Oil', u',', u'Greater', u'Than', u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'Residual', u'Fuel', u'Oil', u',', u'Greater', u'Than', u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'Residual', u'Fuel', u'Oil')
(u'Greater', u'Than', u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'Greater',)
(u'Than', u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'1', u'%', u'Sulfur')
(u'1', u'%')
```

This is not that great since there are some very long chunks that can be further broken down.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

[edit], partial code:

```
for sbt in out.subtrees(lambda t: t.height() < out.height() - 1):
        if sbt.label() in ['ADJP', 'ADVP', 'CONJP', 'NP', 'PP', 'QP', 'UCP', 'VP', 'WHADJP', 'WHAVP', 'WHNP', 'WHPP']:
            candidates.append(tuple(sbt.leaves()))
```

Comment: Check the labels of the subtrees and extract only when it's labelled as NP =)

Comment: Thanks for reply - the above results are extracted from all subtrees labeled 'NP' and 'PP'. It doesn't seem to work because they also include the very long ones that does not chunk the sentences correctly.

Comment: Try harder I believe in you! Notice that the NPs are nested? Play around the no. of levels of NP you want to extract.

Comment: BTW, show the code of how you're extracting other than plainly should which function you're importing.

Comment: let me edit the post! thanks man.